# Where is the Visual Studio Output Path specified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I had a Visual Studio 2010 C# project called "FooTest"  (OK, it wasn't really"Foo", it was something proprietary)

I decided to rename it "FooRegressionTest", so I renamed the directory it was in, and the solution file.  In Solution Explorer I renamed the project to "FooRegressionTest" and I right-clicked on it and in Properties, in the Application tab I renamed the Assembly Name and the Default namespace all to "FooRegressionTest".   In the code I changed the namespace references and everything else from "FooTest" to "FooRegressionTest".

If I do a "find and replace" for filetypes of "`*.*`" searching for "FooTest". I get 0 hits.  So I believe I've converted all references of "FooTest" to "FooRegressionTest".

My program builds and runs fine, **BUT** at build-time the binaries are all placed in a folder called "FooTest".    Where is that folder-name specified?

BTW, in the project Properties, for Build, the Output Path says **bin\Debug**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but your `.exe` is always going to be in `bin\Debug` or `obj\Debug`

Comment: What kind of build are you doing? Just a right-click and build, or some sort of MSBuild script?

Also, do a find/replace inside your actual project and solution files for the old project name.

Comment: Did you re-open the project after renaming it? What is the path of the generated `FooTest` directory, relative to your project directory?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage  no kidding,, but why FooTest\bin\debug and not FooRegressionTest\bin\debug?    I mentioned the Output path because otherwise everyone would try to answer the question by saying it was set there.

Comment: Oops I read your question wrong then -- sorry!

Comment: @ AaronS  (menu:) Build | Build Solution  _or_ Build>Rebuild Solution  _or_ Build>Clean then Build>Rebuild Solution

Answer (score 3):

You typically set the build path like this:

1. Right click on your project, select properties
2. When you see the properties window, select Build (on the left hand side)
3. The output path is displayed (and editable towards the bottom of this page.

The output path is configuratble for different configurations - i.e. you can have it build to one path when building x64, another when building x86 and so on.

In your case, you might have a screwed up csproj file... try unloading the project

1. Right click project
2. select unload
3. right click unloaded project
4. select 'edit project'

have a look for the path in a section of the csproj xml that looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\FooTest</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And change the output path...